# How to reload/refresh view from app delegate?

Tags: ios5, viewcontroller, appdelegate

i'm try to find a way with google to reload/refresh view from app delegate. none of solutions work. my idea was for vie to reload inside `applicationDidBecomeActive:` , but i can't get it to work, it doesnt matter what i try. anyone?

**Update:**

last thing i used (in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` with imported `ViewController.h` in AppDelegate) was:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc viewDidLoad]
```

There were a coupled of other variations, but i think you get what i'm trying to achieve.i'm a rookie so please don't blame me if this is totaly useless :)

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us some code?

Comment: i've update my question.hope it helps you to help me :)

Comment: Actually I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want the app to start from the first view? Try to explain your current situation and what you would want to happen.

Comment: i'm trying to refresh a view if you press home button and go to settings to change them.after u get back to app (app has only one),view should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to perform some action (sending a refresh message to a controller, for example) when the app is reopened?

The method to override is `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your app delegate. You'll want to keep a reference to the view controller in question around. So:

```
@property MyViewController *myView;

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.myView refreshSettings];
}
```

You could probably use `-viewDidLoad` like you did in your example code, if you wanted, but I find it's easier to factor out the part that you want to update and call it from both places.